# Port forwarding to a Gitlab server running on a Docker container

Tags: router, docker, port-forwarding, gitlab, docker-compose

I am trying to setup a gitlab server in my local server and open it to internet access. I followed these steps:

1) Container created using the image at https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab, by running `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/master/docker-compose.yml` and then `docker-compose up`. Everything worked fine and I may access my Gitlab server at http://127.0.0.1:10080, which is the port configured at the `docker-compose.yml`file downloaded.

2) I accessed my router and forwarded port 10080 to my server (internal IP 192.169.0.3) according to [this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUtUA.png).

3) I created an account at http://noip.com, a dynamic DNS service, and configured a server named `emeraldfw.serveblog.net`, pointing to my real IP, found at http://www.whatsmyrealip.com/. I even installed the software to periodically update my IP when it changes.

4) I checked with `dig emeraldfw.serveblog.net` and it responded with my current IP.

5) Finally I pointed my browser to http://emeraldfw.serveblog.net:10080 and... nothing happened! I got a timeout error.

Then I used `nmap` to check my server, doing a `nmap 127.0.0.1` and only two ports were open: 23/tcp (telnet) and 631/tcp (ipp). I thought I would find port 10080 open there!

What exactly I am forgetting? Any suggestion to get this running?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What OS version are you running in your local server?

Comment: I'm running Debian Linux 9 (Stretch).

Comment: You can check if 10080 port is opened with `ss -ntap | grep 10080` you should see a LISTEN. Also if the container is running, you can use docker ps and check if port 10080 is exposed.

Comment: Yes, I see a LISTEN for this port. And `docker ps` says the port is exposed.

Comment: So, if the port 10080 is listening and exposed by Docker, now you can try to browse http://192.168.0.3:10080 from a PC inside your local network and check if you can connect to that port. If not could you paste the result of iptables -L -v so we can check if the port is not opened in your Debian firewall?